# Error when upgrading Spyder to 4.0.1: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently upgraded to Spyder 4.0.1 through Anaconda via `conda update spyder`.  Now, when I try to boot up Spyder via Anaconda Navigator, the program automatically crashes with the following dump:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3718, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3559, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1010, in setup
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/plugin.py", line 52, in 
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.widgets import ClientWidget
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/widgets/__init__.py", line 16, in 
from .debugging import DebuggingWidget
File "/Users/ed/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/widgets/debugging.py", line 22, in 
from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'
```

I couldn't find anybody with a similar error.  I updated IPython, as someone suggested, but it did not resolve the problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

... since none of this worked for me, here how I solved it:

1. check what IPython version you have via `conda list`

   in my case i got a rather old version `5.8.0` instead of the most recent one
   (at the time of writing `7.19.0`... check available versions via `conda search ipython`)
2. since `conda update ipython` did not provide the most recent version, i decided
   to manually run the command that installs the most recent version
   (for me this was `conda install -c conda-forge ipython=7.19.0`)
3. that's it...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Upgrading IPython via the following command line helped resolve the situation.

```
sudo conda update IPython -n xxx
```

where xxx is the name of the environment I was trying to run Spyder in.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I updated IPython and now Spyder 4 loads and stays up for half a second before crashing with a segmentation fault. Progress, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same issue on **Spyder 4.1.4**. Turns out that not all the required packages were installed correctly when I installed Spyder.

I used the following in python to test IPython:

```
import IPython
print(IPython.__version__)
```

Turned out that I had 6.4.0 so I ran the following from the terminal:

```
!pip install --upgrade IPython
```

IPython 7.16.1 was installed with prompt_toolkit-3.0.5. I also got the following errors:

> ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.

> ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.

> ERROR: jupyter-console 5.2.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 3.0.5 which is incompatible.

> ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 has requirement jedi==0.17.1, but you'll have jedi 0.12.1 which is incompatible.

> ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 has requirement parso==0.7.0, but you'll have parso 0.3.0 which is incompatible.

> ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 has requirement qtconsole>=4.6.0, but you'll have qtconsole 4.3.1 which is incompatible.

> ERROR: spyder-kernels 1.9.2 has requirement ipykernel>=5.1.3; python_version > "2", but you'll have ipykernel 4.8.2 which is incompatible.

> ERROR: spyder-kernels 1.9.2 has requirement jupyter-client>=5.3.4, but you'll have jupyter-client 5.2.3 which is incompatible.

Installing the correct versions of the above packages in pip resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update to python 3.7. I had the same problem. That solved it.

conda install python=3.7 anaconda=custom

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Just do conda update IPython. All good then!